# Connecting two routers and configuring 6in4 tunnel for both

Tags: router, ipv6

I have connected two routers,by cable from first router to wan port on second router, configure second private subnet, configure routing, turn off NAT on second(nested) router, and all working fine.

First router have ipv6 6in4 tunnel config, and it working fine for clients of that router. PC connected to second router don't receive ipv6 ip, as expected. So, I receive one more tunnel from broker and configure it. It uses same public ip address. Working fine for a little while, then ipv6 stop working.

Question is, how to configure 6in4 tunnel(or two) for two routers, one behind another, with one public ip? Routers are very simple, for home use.

Btw, second router didn't receive ipv6 ip from first, only ipv4 by dhcp. It capable to setup few types of ipv6 tunnels, or static ipv6.

Tunel provider probably Hurricane Electric, I don't remember exactly. Below ip settings of first router(front, working) tunnel:

```
Ipv6-in-ipv4 tunnel

LAN IPv6 Setting
Static IPv6 address:    2a03:e2c0:xxx:5555::2
Enable router advertisements: yes

WAN IPv6 Setting
Static or local IPv6 address: 2a03:e2c0:xxx::2
Remote IPv6 gateway: 2a03:e2c0:xxx::1

DNS Server: 2001:4860:4860::8888
6in4 IPv4 remote endpoint: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Second, nested router not configured as bridge, instead it is a router without NAT. Ipv4 lan and wan configured and works. May be it should be a bridge, but it only allows WiFi bridge what is not a choice because of low level of signal.

Comment: A second tunnel is unnecessary. What size IPv6 network do you have routed to the first router?

Comment: /64 , really few computers. They don't receive ipv6 ip when behind second router without second tunnel. If I dont need it, may be I can split one, to write something in second router tunnel settings?

Comment: What's your tunnel provider?

Comment: I updated question, not sure of tunnel broker but there are ip prefixes, what should point to one.

Comment: That IP range is not HE. Whois says its ipv6.ip4market.ru